# BizTalk Default Pipeline XML Receive - Error Code -1061153241

Tags: biztalk

Looking in the BizTalk Admin Console under tracked service instances and I can see that the default XML Receive pipeline starts, however it never completes.  It remains at status "started" with the error code set to -1061153241.  In tracked message events I can see the pipeline receives the message, however i can't see a "send" event type and it looks like the message is not sent to the MessageBox for the waiting orchestration to pick it up.  My orchestration never gets initiated.  There are no error messages in the event log, no suspended service instances, just the tracked service instance showing starting and not completed with the error code specified above.

Comment: Googling that error number comes up with the following description for the error "The batch operation Submit failed with HRESULT -1061154045. Moving the message to the suspend queue."  Are you doing any de-batching?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  No, i'm not performing any debatching.  I must admit I searched google and didn't manage to find anything about the error at all.

Comment: Does the message validate in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue.  I had previously just GAC'd a dll and didn't update it as a resource in the Admin Console.  Once I updated the Admin Console with this resource and restarted host instances the error went away.  Thanks.